# File Delete and Rename in Java

Tags: java, file

I have the following Java code which will search in an xml for a specific tag and then will add some text to it and save that file. I couldnt find a way to rename the emporary file to the original file. Please suggest.

```
import java.io.*;

    class ModifyXML {

         public void readMyFile(String inputLine) throws Exception
         {

            String record = "";

            File outFile = new File("tempFile.tmp");

            FileInputStream fis  = new FileInputStream("InfectiousDisease.xml");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fos);

            while ( (record=br.readLine()) != null ) 
            {
                 if(record.endsWith("<add-info>"))
                 {
                     out.println("    "+"<add-info>");
                     out.println("    "+inputLine);              
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     out.println(record);
                 }

            }
           out.flush();
           out.close();
           br.close();
           //Also we need to delete the original file
           //outFile.renameTo(InfectiousDisease.xml);//Not working

         }

         public static void main (String[] args) {
             try
             {
             ModifyXML f = new ModifyXML();
             f.readMyFile("This is infectious disease data");
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete and rename a file in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362067/delete-and-rename-a-file-in-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First delete the original file and then rename the new file:

```
File inputFile = new File("InfectiousDisease.xml");
File outFile = new File("tempFile.tmp");

if(inputFile.delete()){
   outFile.renameTo(inputFile);
}
```

Comment: Yes its working. Thanks a lot. I thought creating a new input file wont be any good.

Answer (score 1):

A good method to rename files is.

```
File file = new File("path-here");
file.renameTo(new File("new path here"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code there are several issues.

First your description mentions renameing the original file and adding some text to it.  Your code doesn't do that, it opens two files, one for reading and one for writing (with the additional text).  That is the right way to do things, as adding text in-place is not really feasible using the techniques you are using.

The second issue is that you are opening a temporary file.  Temporary files remove themselves upon closing, so all the work you did adding your text disappears as soon as you close the file.

The third issue is that you are modifying XML files as plain text.  This sometimes works as XML files are a subset of plain text files, but there is no indication that you attempted to ensure that the output file was an XML file.  Perhaps you know more about your input files than is mentioned, but if you want this to work correctly for 100% of the input cases, you probably want to create a SAX writer that writes out all a SAX reader reads, with the additional information in the correct tag location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
outFile.renameTo(new File(newFileName));
```

You have to ensure these files are not open at the time.

Comment: it is renameTo instead of rename