# Android RenameTo leaves empty file

Tags: android, android-file

Could you please help me. `renameTo()` leaves empty old file. So I see 2 files in file system with new name and old name. The size of old file is `0`. If I delete old file after renaming it says that file does not exist while staying in file system.

An absolute path of directory is:

```
/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera
```

My code:

```
       String dir = oldpath.substring(0, oldpath.lastIndexOf("/"));

        File directory = new File(dir);
        File from      = new File(directory, oldfilename);
        File to        = new File(directory, newname);

        renamed = from.renameTo(to);
```

Comment: what you are trying to do?

Comment: i want to let user to change file name

Comment: What is `newname`?  Step through with the debugger.

Comment: Some name like abc.mp4

Comment: its been deleted, i guess you need to send broadcast to the OS to scan for new files and make all the changes automatically.

Comment: No, it remains after phone restarting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
File sdcard = new File("/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera");
File from = new File(sdcard, "from.txt"); // Don't forget to set the file extension.
File to = new File(sdcard, "to.txt"); // In this case, we have a '.txt' file extension.
from.renameTo(to);
```

You can get the sdcard directory in `String` type programmatically by using this code:

```
String sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
```

Don't forget to add this permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of an empty version of the old file remaining in the storage

Comment: this is the exact way, you shouldn't forget about file extetion

Answer (score 1):

RenameTo leaves an empty copy of the original file if the file is opened by another process.

For example, I wanted to rename a file after the DownloadManager finished downloading it. The DownloadManager apparently notifies the BroadcastReceivers after the download, but before closing the file. This caused the renameTo in the onReceive to leave an empty copy. To solve this problem, I had to make the BroadcastReceiver to wait half a second before renaming the file.

Comment: I have met this too, and I did file delete after 5s. It also works.but this solution maybe better.

Answer (score 0):

You must remember about two things : The file and the file extension (file type). The following is wrong way sometimes, in case of deleting and renaming file :

```
File file = new File (dir+"/"+myfile)
```

The right way is :

```
File file = new File (dir, myfile+".db");
```

For the  Full Aprroach, you could look at [Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68622444/7608371).